# Rails 4 routing parameter that looks like a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a `Entity` model with an `entity_type` attribute that can be `Hospital` or `Clinic`.

I would like to be able to refer to things in the abstract:

- `/entities`
- `/entities/us`
- `/entities/us/mn+md`

And the specific:

- `/hospitals`
- `/hospitals/us`
- `/hospitals/us/mn+md`

I'm having difficulty with the routing.  I can't seem to get the `entity_type` parameter to work.

`routes.rb`:

```
get "/:entity_type/(:country_code/(:region_code))" => "entities#index", :constraints => {
  :entity_type=>["entities","hospitals","clinics"], 
  :country_code=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}([\+\,][a-zA-Z]{2})*/,
  :region_code=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}([\+\,][a-zA-Z]{2})*/
}

...

# remaining RESTful routes
resources :entities
resources :apps
```

The `entities_controller#index` method:

```
def index

  @entities = Entity.all

  # probably a better way to do this
  @entities = @entities.by_type(params[:entity_type]) if ( params[:entity_type].present? && params[:entity_type]!='entities')

  # location-specific; works as expected
  @entities = @entities.for_country(params[:country_code]) if params[:country_code].present?
  @entities = @entities.for_region(params[:region_code]) if params[:region_code].present?

end
```

Corresponding `entity.rb` method:

```
# probably a better way to do this
def self.by_type(entity_type)
  return where("entity_type='#{entity_type.singularize.titleize}'") if entity_type != 'entities'
end
```

Comment: Define "can't get the entity_type parameter to work". If nothing else, you have to have this route listed before anything else that could map the entity type to something else.

Comment: It is the first route listed.

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

```
:entity_type=>["entities","hospitals","clinics"]
```

to:

```
:entity_type=>/(entities|hospitals|clinics)/
```